# Space to right and left inside EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, padding

I'm trying to create an `EditText` with 2 buttons inside (right and left). I want to give it a padding on each side so that the text not appears behind the buttons. But I can not. I tried with `padding, margin`... but nothing works for me. What can be the error?

```
                   <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/buscar_linear"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone" >

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_monumento"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="15"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:hint="Buscar..."
                                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                                android:textStyle="bold" >
                            </EditText>

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_lupa"
                                android:layout_width="22dp"
                                android:layout_height="22dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/buscar_lupa" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_salir"
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/buscar_salir" />
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
```

**NEW CODE**

```
                  <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/buscar_linear"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone" >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_monumento"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="15"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:hint="Buscar..."
                                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                                android:textStyle="bold" >
                            </EditText>

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_lupa"
                                android:layout_width="22dp"
                                android:layout_height="22dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/buscar_lupa" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_salir"
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/buscar_salir" />

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all,Framelayout, should host only one View.
Second, You didn't put the 2 buttons inside the EditText.

Comment: Just remove the FrameLayout.

Comment: I'm trying without Framelayout. But the buttons disappear

Answer (score 0):

don't use FrameLayout, use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) instead
framelayout is best used for single item, or wrap LinearLayout around the Button and TextView if you insists on using FrameLayout
or better, change the parent viewgroup LinearLayout to RelativeLayout, else the ADT will tell a warning about the useless viewgroup

Comment: I'm trying without Framelayout. But the buttons disappear with android:layout_width="wrap_parent" in EditText

Comment: are you sure framelayout is for single item? where did u get this?

Comment: Edit "width" in EditText to "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent"

Comment: I have changed and it not works for me. Code updated

Comment: the padding not exists

Comment: @nizammoidu the android reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html "FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item"

Comment: @user3660058 did you mean "wrap_content" ? it disappear because you didn't give any android:text to the button, so it wraps nothing, btw why do you want the button to be inside of the edittext? edittext is not a viewgroup so it can't contain Buttons or any other views, that's why use RelativeLayout if you want the Button to overlay the EditText

Answer (score 0):

If you just need two buttons on the sides of edit text simplest way is this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buscar_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/buscar_lupa"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/buscar_monumento"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="15"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Buscar..sdsdsdsds."
                android:text="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="#f00"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </EditText>



            <Button android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/buscar_salir"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this code will put the buttons out of the edittext. I want to show the buttons inside

Comment: u cant put any view inside editText. but you can make it look like inside, that may  or may not work in different screen config, device themes, editText/Button background Images. or you could setup view group like above with carefully designed background images.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your new code segment you have the parent linear layout visibility set to gone

Secondly use a relative layout it's simple

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/buscar_monumento"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="15"
    android:hint="Buscar..."
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:textColor="@color/negro"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buscar_lupa"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buscar_lupa" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buscar_salir"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buscar_salir" />
```